# Fix column width in RecycleView when changing density

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm working with multiple columns in `RecycleView`. For the sake of simplification, the following example contains only a `ref` column which I expect to be displayed on one line and a `message` column that should take the rest of the screen, the text being wrapped in order to be fully readable. Both columns are implemented using `MDLabel` instances:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from random import randrange
from loremipsum import get_sentences


Builder.load_string('''
<RVLayout>:
    spacing: 2
    size_hint: None, None
    height: message.texture_size[1]
    MDLabel:
        size_hint_x: None # label width should fit text
        halign: 'center'
        text: root.ref
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.bg_darkest
    MDLabel:
        id: message
        text: root.message
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.bg_darkest

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'RVLayout'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        spacing: 2
        default_size: None, dp(10)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')

class RVLayout(BoxLayout):
    ref = StringProperty()
    message = StringProperty()

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.height = self.ids.message.texture_size[1]

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [
            {
                'ref': str(x).zfill(8), 
                'message': ' '.join(get_sentences(randrange(1, 4)))
            } for x in range(50)]

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

As you can see, I wrote an `on_size` method to my `RVLayout` so that everything looks well on resize (desktop case):

[image]

The height of the `message` elements fits perfectly for any window width, while the width of `ref` stays the same:

[image]

Now here comes my issue, when I start my app with a density > 1, the `ref` column width is still the same even though the font is bigger. For instance with the environment variable `KIVY_METRICS_DENSITY=2` I get the following:

[image]

How can I make `ref` width adapt to the density?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using adaptive size like suggested by @JohnAnderson put me on the right track. The sole problem is that the size is adapted on x and y axis. Thus the `ref` labels are not the same height as the `message` ones, which doesn't look great:

[image]

Playing with `size_hint_y` and `size_y` didn't help until I switched from `BoxLayout` to `GridLayout` and set `size_hint_y: root.height`:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from random import randrange
from loremipsum import get_sentences


Builder.load_string('''
<RVLayout>:
    cols: 2
    spacing: 2
    size_hint: None, None
    height: message.texture_size[1]
    MDLabel:
        adaptive_size: True
        size_hint_y: root.height
        padding_x: dp(5)
        halign: 'center'
        text: root.ref
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.bg_darkest
    MDLabel:
        id: message
        text: root.message
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.bg_darkest

<RV>:
    viewclass: 'RVLayout'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        spacing: 2
        default_size: None, dp(10)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
''')

class RVLayout(GridLayout):
    ref = StringProperty()
    message = StringProperty()

    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.height = self.ids.message.texture_size[1]

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [
            {
                'ref': str(x).zfill(8), 
                'message': ' '.join(get_sentences(randrange(1, 4)))
            } for x in range(50)]

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

`pos_hint` isn't needed anymore in this case.

Now things look great for any density:

`density==1`:

[image]

`density==2`:

[image]

Edit: using `adaptive_width: True` with BoxLayout works too

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
MDLabel:
    size_hint_x: None # label width should fit text
```

to:

```
MDLabel:
    adaptive_size: True
    pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.5}
    # size_hint_x: None # label width should fit text
```

Using `adaptive_size` will size the `MDLabel` to the size of its text.

Comment: Thanks! specifying `adaptive_size` was the key! In order to get a satisfying label height, I had to switch to `GridLayout` though. I posted the corresponding code as an answer.